# How do I connect to the internet with 3g usb modem (mobile broadband connection) in OpenBSD?

Tags: openbsd, modem, 3g

In order to install the GUI in OpenBSD! I know how to connect to wifi but now I have only 3g-usb-modem Huawei E171 and I don`t know how to connect to the internet via 3g-usb-modem in OpenBSD ! How can I solve it ? Please help me !

Comment: Could you paste here your dmesg ?